# Overcome memory limitation when downloading from database into Orange

Tags: python, data-mining, databases, orange

I would like to run the association rule mining algorithm of the Orange library on a dataset that is stored in a PostgreSQL database. The table 'buildingset' contains the itemsets for each user, thus each record is related to a user, and each field is related to an item. The values are either 1 (smallint) or missing. The table has about 14,000 records and 31 fields.

When I try to run the algorithm on this dataset, I get the following error:

> `ValueError Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/opt/orange/orange3/Orange/canvas/scheme/widgetsscheme.py", line 722, in process_signals_for_widget
>       handler(*args)
>     File "/home/bdukai/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/orangecontrib/associate/widgets/owassociate.py", line 444, in set_data
>       self.X = data.X
>     File "/opt/orange/orange3/Orange/data/sql/table.py", line 353, in X
>       self.download_data(AUTO_DL_LIMIT)
>     File "/opt/orange/orange3/Orange/data/sql/table.py", line 333, in download_data
>       raise ValueError("Too many rows to download the data into memory.")
>   ValueError: Too many rows to download the data into memory.`

Thus is there any way overcome this limitation, without upgrading the hardware?

Comment: could you share how you could connect with SQL table, I downloaded freeDTS ( don't know how to install it) as well as running pip install pymssql in command line ( completed with no issue). But nothing change. I try to use file widget, but I could only get 60K row out of 1 Million. thanks

Comment: I haven't used Orange since then and I honestly don't remember, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "download data to local memory" checkbox in SQL Table widget, it should allow you to work with up to 1000000 rows.

[image]